# Normalising this database structure

Tags: database-design, relational, rdbms

We need help normalising the following database structure and we're a bit stumped.

Here's the current structure:

Templates

```
  id - primary
  name
  ...
```

Languages

```
  id - primary
  name
  code
  ...
```

Template Languages

```
  id - primary
  templateId - foreign to templates.id
  languageId - foreign to languages.id
  ...
```

Template Boxes

```
  id - primary
  templateId - foreign to templates.id
```

Translations

```
   id - primary
   templateLanguageId - foreign to templateLanguages.id
   templateBoxId - foreign to templateBoxes.id
   ...
```

The issue we have is a `translations` record should belong to a single template but currently it could belong to two separate ones depending on the link of the template languages record and template boxes record.

I could add `templateId` to `translations` but the structure would still not be normalised.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's difficult without an explanation of the problem you're trying to design a database for.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - Translations should be linked to a single template language and a single template box and those two relations should be linked to the same template.

EDIT: Currently it's possible to link a translation to a box which is linked to e.g. Template A, and a language that is linked to e.g. Template B - this should never be allowed to happen

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.